# Is there any API in Selenium to collect errors from chrome Extension?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-extension, selenium-chromedriver

I want to collect errors from a particular chrome extension in my testing project. Is there a way to collect it through any direct selenium API.

One solution I found out is to navigate to chrome://extensions/?errors= and extract the error data from the HTML DOM. But I was looking for a straightforward way to do it.

Comment: The underlying CDP can eavesdrop on any console message including errors ([Log](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Log) and [Runtime](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Runtime#event-exceptionThrown) events) so Selenium should be able to use that.

Comment: For capturing errors from Chrome extension I need to collect console log from background script of extension. Can you show me an example of how can it be done.